# Whats the difference in creating an object using init versus the standard way?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My confusion comes from the the code like below.   What is the main difference and when would you use the first example rather than the other? Both create objects but I don't understand the difference in them.

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder  {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.text = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"Text"];
        self.checked = [aDecoder decodeBoolForKey:@"Checked"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

compared to say:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

Comment: The first is an implementation of a particular init method.  The second is an invocation of a different, simpler init method.  The first is initializing the object.  The second is asking the callee to initialize the object.

Comment: The title of the question is slightly confusing - `init` _is_ the standard way, I'd say.

Comment: Are you asking what `initWithCoder:` is for?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Are you asking why one of them uses `alloc` and `init`, while the other just calls `[super init]`, without any alloc? It's not entirely clear what the two different ways you're asking about are.

Comment: @Monolo I know it was a little confusing hence why I used the examples below to try and help!  I was trying to determine why one would be prefered over the other.

Comment: @BJHomer Yes that is one of the things I was asking, and wondering why one would be a preferred use over the other.

Comment: @OralB I was thinking the same thing. Maybe I wasn't clear enough? But thats why I provided the examples. Oh well got my help anyways!

Comment: @kenthub yes - what I meant is that your title is confusing, as it implies that `init` is not standard. This is wrong, as `init` _is_ the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first instance, you are instructing a class/subclass as to how to behave upon initiation in the implementation (.m file) of the class/subclass, whereas in the second example, you are initiating an existing object into a variable.

Hope this helps. I'll be happy to clarify further if needed.

reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html

Comment: Thanks that link helped a whole lot more that the tutorials explanation that I am following.

Comment: glad to have helped :) good luck!